# How to determine when a value reaches 1 Million, then 1 Billion, and so on?

Tags: actionscript-3, biginteger

I am currently using the BigInteger as3 class (https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/math/BigInteger.as) to allow my game work with very big numbers, to essentially allow the player of my game to become really "rich" and become a Billionare, Quintillionaire, and far beyond this. When using Number format or Integer, the MAX_VALUE is quite low for what I want to accomplish, so I have opted to use BigInteger.as

However, I have 2 problems.

1) When a value suprasses 1 million I begin to display the number as such (e.g. 1 Million, instead of 1,000,000). This works fine. However, when I start to display value such as 1,000, 2,000, 3000 and so on, I notice these low-end values are represented differently. E.g. 10,000 is a000, and 11,000 is b000. I am aware that BigInteger doesn't use the typical format of numbers in its approach. When I call intValue() or valueOf() I get values where 1000 is 8192, 2000 is 12288. (I have checked this via a loop by adding '1000' repeatedly.

Here is my code to loop through big integer and check. The function WordNumbers.getWordNumbers() basically asks for the BigInteger value to be passed, and from there will work out the word name (e.g. 1 million or 1000, depending what BigInteger's value is) and will output bigInteger.intValue() etc. Point-being, can't seem to find a solution!

```
private function NewTesting():void {
        var popUpString:String = '';

        //Use BigInteger instead
        var addAmount:BigInteger = new BigInteger('1000');
        var sum:BigInteger = new BigInteger('1000');

        var resultsPerPage:Number = 10;
        var totalPages:Number = 5;
        var totalResults:Number = resultsPerPage*totalPages;

        popUpString += 'Starting at value '+sum+'...';
        popUpString += '<br /><br />';

        var i:int;
        for (i=0;i<=totalResults;i++){              
            sum = sum.add('1000');

            popUpString += 'Adding 1000...';
            popUpString += 'Value: '+sum+' - Word: '+WordNumbers.getWordNumbers(sum,0);
            popUpString += '<br /><br />';

            if (i!=0){
                if (i % resultsPerPage == 0){
                    PopUps.HTMLPopUp(popUpString);
                    popUpString = '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, before anyone says I should check other posts first - I have done so. They have not made any sense to me what-so-ever and I am unsure if they are using the same as3-crypto library as I am.

My second problem 2). Is mainly that I realise I now don't have access to any decimal places due to using "Big Integers" rather than a "Big Number". So, if I want to display to the user "1.553 Million" then I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to provide an answer to my own question which I believe I have resolved. I hope this can help others.

If looking to work with very big numbers in AS3 I would recommend using Graniteds library. See here: https://github.com/graniteds/graniteds/blob/master/reference-docs/src/asciidoc/graniteds-bignumbers-flex.adoc

With the above I can now use a Big Number (using BigDecimal.as).

Answer (score 0):

You should try reading the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

You have to use bit manipulation to get the values.

Comment: Im not sure these are the same as as3 crypto library isnt a full port. Could you explain how to actually do this with bit manipulation? I don’t have the slightest idea